# Delegate processing during Tomcat startup with Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat

I have defined a bean which needs to do some heavy processing during the @PostConstruct lifecycle phase (during start up).

As it stands, I submit a new Callable to an executor service with each iteration of the processing loop. I keep a list of the Future objects returned from these submissions in a member variable.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class StartupManager implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    private final Map<Class<?>, Optional<Action>> actionMappings = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final List<Future> processingTasks = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        this.controllers.getHandlerMethods().entrySet().stream().forEach(handlerItem -> {

            processingTasks.add(executorService.submit(() -> {

                // processing

            }));

        });

    }

}
```

This same bean implements the ApplicationListener interface, so it can listen for a ContextRefreshedEvent which allows me to detect when the application has finished starting up. I use this handler to loop through the list of Futures and invoke the blocking get method which ensures that all of the processing has occurred before the application continues.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent  applicationEvent) {
    for(Future task : this.processingTasks) {
        try {
            task.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My first question... Is changing the actionMapping stream to a parallelStream going to achieve the same thing as submitting a task to the executor service? Is there a way I can pass an existing executor service into a parallel stream for it to use the thread pool size i've defined for the bean?

Secondly.. As part of the processing.. The actionMappings map is read and entries are put in there. It is sufficient enough to make this Map a ConcurrentHashMap to make it thread safe in this scenario?

And secondly is implementing the ApplicationListener interface and listening for the ContextRefreshedEvent the best way to detect when the application has startedup and therefore force complete the un-processed tasks by blocking? Or can this be done another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. About using `parallelStream()`: No, and this is precisely the main drawback of using this method. It should be used only when the thread pool size doesn't matter, so I think your `ExecutorService`-based approach is fine.

   Since you are working with Java 8, you could as well use the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` method, which has an overload that takes an `Executor`. Since `ExecutorService` extends `Executor`, you can pass it your `ExecutorService` and you're done!
2. I think a `ConcurrentHashMap` is fine. It ensures thread safety in all its operations, especially when comes the time to add or modify entries.
3. When is a `ContextRefreshedEvent` fired? According to the Javadoc:

   > *Event raised when an `ApplicationContext` gets initialized or refreshed.*

   which doesn't guarantee your `onApplicationEvent()` method is to be called once and only once, that is, when your bean is properly initialized, which includes execution of the `@PostConstruct`-annotated method.

   I suggest you implement the `BeanPostProcessor` interface and put your `Future`-checkup logic in the `postProcessAfterInitialization()` method. The two `BeanPostProcessor`methods are called before and after the `InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()` method (if present), respectively.

I hope this will be helpful...

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: Thanks for the answers Jeff, your points a very clear and concise. One question regarding the BeanPostProcessor.. As i understood, the postProcessAfterInitialization() method is called per bean, after it has been initialised. I'm after an event which is raised when all beans have been initialised in the context. This allows a little more time for the processing tasks to complete naturally before issuing the blocking call.